# How to make a promise resolve with a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to JavaScript and I really got confused by the documentation about promises.
I have the following case here where I have a punch of users and for each user I execute an async function in which I do some calculations on that user and add the result along with the user to an array. From what I understood from the documentation that I need to get a promise for each time the async function is executed and add all the promises to a list of promises that resolve when the resultant array is passed to it as following:

```
 someFunction = () => {
   var promises = [];
   users.forEach(user => {
       var promise = asyncFunction(user).callback(callBackValue => {
         // Run some checks and add the user to an array with the result
         if (checksAreGood) {
           usersArray.push({user: user, result: callBackValue});
         }
       });
       promises.push(promise);
   });
   return Promise.all(promises).then(() => Promise.resolve(matches));
 };
```

Question is: if the number of the users I am traversing is unknown and I want to limit the number of users added to the array to 20 if and only if the number of users are more than 20 otherwise add all the users. In other words, resolve the promise when the array is full of 20 users or less.
The purpose for this is to avoid executing the async functions for the whole number of users given to optimize performance. Means, if I have 1000 users I want the async function to be executed until the array is full to 20 only.

Comment: you are not pushing promises in the promise array.

Comment: what about the line "promises.push(promise)" ?

Comment: it wont work actually

Comment: It actually does

Comment: @zabusa he is adding the promises into the array

Comment: @you are not passing an promise to the.Promise.all() then what you saying it works?

Comment: @AhmedSamy what does the asyncFunction(user) return

Comment: also what does the .callback() return

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff i cant see any promises.returned by asynfunction

Comment: it returns a promise ... it is Firebase query function that calls a callback with a snapshot from the database

Comment: does the `.callback(...)` return a promise?

Comment: Yes it does otherwise I wouldn't have typed var promise = .....

Comment: also I think doing `users.slice(0, 20).forEach(...)` will work (only looping over the first 20 users)

Comment: Guys the code snippet actually works and the array is fetched perfectly my question is how to modify it to limit the array size to 20 users or less

Comment: What do you mean the number of users is unknown? Can't you do a check for users.length?

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff No it won't work as sometimes the asyncFunctions checking conditions might fail and the user won't be added to the array

Comment: @brickingup Unknown like variable ... I have no control over

Comment: oh. I guess there are two things that you could do. 1) do one loop through where you validate first, then slice the first 20 of the validated ones, but that wont be possible in all cases. but 2) you could try `if (usersArray.length < 20) usersArray.push(...)`

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff the first will work but doesn't serve the purpose why I am limiting the users to 20 in the first place which is saving the machine from traversing the whole users fetched from database which is a nightmare. The later I am going to try and let you know

Comment: Say if you have 30 users and when you define the promise the asyncFunction is called immediately. So in your code 30 asyncFunctions are called at the same time. Before the results return, you don't know how many checking conditions will pass and how many users will be returned. So you have to run all the asyncFunctions to find out. If you don't want to run all the asyncFunctions you need to run them sequentially and decide whether to run the next one based on the previous results, but that will be much slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first solution which only searches until 20 users where found would be to traverse *one user after another* :

```
 async function someFunction(){
  const results = [];
  for(const user of users){
     const result = await asyncFunction(user);
     // Run some checks and add the user to an array with the result
     if(!someChecksGood) continue;
     results.push(result);
     if(results.length >= 20) break;
  }
  return results;
 }
```

While this works "perfect", its quite slow as it only processes one request at a time. So the opposite solution would be to run all requests at a time and cancel them if the array is already full:

```
 async function someFunction(){
  const results = [];
  async function process(user){
    const result = await asyncFunction(user);
    if(!someChecksGood || results.length >= 20) return;
    results.push(result);
   }
   await Promise.all(users.map(process));
   return results;
 }
```

But now there is a high number of unneccessary requests, that are discarded afterwards. To improve this, one could combine both approaches above by "chunking" the requests, which should not decrease request time that much as dbs can only process a certain amount of requests at a time, but the good thing is that we can stop processing when the array is full, and only the rest of the "chunk" is unneccessary proccessed, so in average it should be better than both solutions above:

```
  async function someFunction(){
    //Chunk the users
    const chunks = [], size = 5;
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i += size)
      chunks.push( users.slice(i, i + size));
    //the method to create the results:
    const results = [];
    async function process(user){
      const result = await asyncFunction(user);
      if(!someChecksGood || results.length >= 20) return;
      results.push(result);
    }
    //iterate over the chunks:
    for(const chunk of chunks){
      await Promise.all(chunk.map(process));
      if(results.length >= 20) break;
    }
    return results;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second is almost what I am looking for. Only problem is, when the length of the array is >= 20 the user is not going to be pushed to the array ... yes that is good ... but still if I have 100 users the async function is going to be executed 100 times which is more processing than what is actually needed.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd version. Although the first chunk could best be the size of 20 + average amount of failures. (and the amount of failures can also be used to figure out how big the 2nd chunk could be)

Comment: @ahmed the first and the second snippet are actually just part of the explanation of the third, which is the real answer ;)

Comment: @JonasW. Yes I can see that :D ... I noticed the your update after I wrote the comment so will check it out and let you know

Comment: @JonasW. I meant no offence to your answer :) It's a great answer and very detailed already. I don't think the answer should always be refined to be copy-pasted as-is. My comment is more for others that might have missed a possible optimisation. In general the async function would already be a request to a batch.

Comment: @rené i saw it as an extension of my answer, so i added an extension to you extension ;)